# Properties of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem, regarding compact operators.

> Let $T$ and $S$ be bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Prove or disprove the following statements:
>
> 1. If $T^n=I$ for some $n$, then $T$ is not compact.
> 2. If $T^2=0$ then $T$ is compact.
> 3. If $TS$ is compact then either $T$ or $S$ is compact.

The definition of compactness that I'm familiar with is: a linear operator $T$ is compact if and only if whenever $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence, $(Tx_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

*What I've done*: For (1), I have seen the proof that an idempotent operator is compact if and only if it has finite rank. For (2), I am not sure how to start. For (3), I have only been able to prove the converse (if either $T$ or $S$ is compact than $TS$ is compact).

Any help on this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints to help you along the way.

Use the converse of (3) to show that the negation of (1) is false (i.e., (1) is true).

For (2), consider weighted shift operators, with sequence of weights $(1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$.  Show this operator is non-compact but squares to zero.

For (3), the answer to (2) shows that this is false.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $T^n=I$ and $T$ is compact, then $T^n$ would be compact and so would be the identity, which is not possible in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.
2. Let $H$ be the space of square summable sequences and $T\colon (x_k)_{k\geq 1}\mapsto (\lambda_k x_{k+1})_{k\geqslant 1}$, where $\lambda_k=1$ if $k$ is even and $\lambda_k=0$ if $k$ is odd.